# API test returns InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: robot framework

Tags: robotframework

The first time I use Library HttpLibrary.HTTP with robot framework.
my api url is something like:
`https://www.app.com:8080/rest/api/customer/phone/personnalData`
when i open this url with google chrome it works and I get as response
`{"phone":false}`

I try to do the same with robot framework:

```
Create Http Context https://www.app.com:8080/rest/api/customer/phone  /personnalData 
Set Request Header    Content-Type    application/json
Set Request Header    Accept    application/json
HttpLibrary.HTTP.GET    https://www.app.com:8080/rest/api/customer/phone  /personnalData 
${Body}=    HttpLibrary.HTTP.Get Response Body
JSON.Save Json    ${Body}    C:/RESTResponseBody.json
```

I got this response:
    `[ FAIL | InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '9448/rest/api/customer/phone/personnalData' ]`

Any help please.

Comment: Is the actual url exactly as you've given it in the question? I'm asking, because in the question the port is 8080, while in the exception it's 9448 - and there's no such string in the sample url. If you don't want to share the exact url that's ok, but in substituting the confidential parts try to preserve the overall structure as-is.

Comment: of course the url is not the real one and 8080 is different from 9448.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So is the port number in the error message the same one as the one in the URL? Asking, because it very well may be because of a proxy that you have configured on the execution machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use http lib in below way.

```
Create Http Context      host=www.app.com:8080   scheme=https 
Set Request Header    Content-Type    application/json
Set Request Header    Accept    application/json
HttpLibrary.HTTP.GET    /rest/api/customer/phone  /personnalData 
${Body}=    HttpLibrary.HTTP.Get Response Body
JSON.Save Json    ${Body}    C:/RESTResponseBody.json
```